# zeppelin 8.1 on emr 5.27 saving notebooks on S3 can't change STORAGE value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I want to use Zeppelin with my spark EMR cluster but I don't figure out how to have it saving my notebooks on s3.

Here is the classification configuration I'm giving to EMR:

```
{
        "classification": "zeppelin-env",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "classification": "export",
                "properties": {
                    "ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_ENDPOINT": "https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/bucket-data-pipeline/?region=eu-west-2",
                    "ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_BUCKET": "bucket-data-pipeline",
                    "ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_USER": "anonymous",
                    "ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_STORAGE":"org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo,org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.S3NotebookRepo"
                }
            }
        ],
        "properties": {}
    }
```

So far, I can see that the configuration is changing on the configuration panel from Zeppelin:

```
zeppelin.notebook.s3.bucket: bucket-data-pipeline
zeppelin.notebook.s3.endpoint: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/bucket-data-pipeline
zeppelin.notebook.s3.sse: false
zeppelin.notebook.s3.user: anonymous
zeppelin.notebook.storage: org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo, (<- ?)
```

but as you can see the storage isn't taking the S3NotebookRepo. If I only put "org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.S3NotebookRepo" Zeppelin doesn't even start properly.

Any ideas how to configure this properly with EMR?

Regarding IAM, the EMR cluster is running with the default EMR_DefaultRole which has read / write to s3